# Allview Viva C701 can't be used in MTP mode on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mtp

When plugging in this Android tablet after a second or two, I get an error message:

> No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Mount' on object at path
>   /org/gtk/vfs/mount/1

The file system is not shown. Only PTP mode works but not MTP. UMS mode is not supported it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This tablet may appear under a number of names but the USB ID remains the same when using `lsusb`:

```
ID 1f3a:1006
```

When in PTP mode, the ID changes to:

```
ID 1f3a:1008
```

Anyway, the problem is fixed by modifying two files.

First, I needed to add this entry into `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`:

```
# Allwiew Viva c701
ATTR{idVendor}=="1f3a", ATTR{idProduct}=="1006", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Then add the following line to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-special_mtp_device.rules` (if the file does not exist, create it):

```
# Allwiew Viva c701
ATTR{idVendor}=="1f3a", ATTR{idProduct}=="1006", MODE=”0666"
```

Reboot. Your tablet should now appear in the file manager.